# Store documents of different collections within the same array

Tags: mongoose

In Mongoose you can do something like:

```
var questionSchema = new Schema({
  comments: [{type: ObjectId, ref: 'Comment'}]
})
```

And later you can [populate](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html) it.

But is there a way to store documents of different collections in the same array?  Something like:

```
var questionSchema = new Schema({
  commentsAndAnswers: [{type: ObjectId, ref: 'Comment'}, {type: ObjectId, ref: 'Answer'}]
})
```

Obviously this won't work, but you see what I mean.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can suggest three solutions for your problem.

**First solution** is to store `ObjectID`s without `ref`s to the other collection:

```
var questionSchema = new Schema({
  comments: [ObjectId]
})
```

It'll work fine, but you'll need to [specify the model to populate](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-populate) for each query:

```
Question.findOne().populate('comments', Answer).exec(next)
```

But I'm not sure that you'll be able to populate `comments` using both `Comment` and `Answer` models.

**The other solution** is to store `comments` as objects with `ref`s:

```
var questionSchema = new Schema({
  comments: [{
      comment: {type: ObjectId, ref: 'Comment'}
      answer: {type: ObjectId, ref: 'Answer'}
    }]
})
```

Now you can populate both comments and answers in a single query:

```
Question.findOne().populate('comments.comment comments.answer').exec(next)
```

If you want to see them in a single array you can add a [virtual](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#virtualtype_VirtualType-get):

```
questionSchema.virtual('comments_and_answers').get(function () {
  return this.comments.map(function (c) {
    return c.comment || c.answer
  });
})
```

You can rid of the original array using [toObject transfer function](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#toJSON).

**Finally**, you may redesign your schema to store comments and answers in a single collection using the same mongoose model for both.

Answer (score 0):

The schema type of mongoose supports [mixed](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html) type, you can use it like this:

```
var questionSchema = new Schema({
    commentsAndAnswers: [Schema.Types.Mixed]
})
```

Then you should be able to insert the document with any schema type to this field.